# Tengo un problema con el scroll jqeury

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola muy buenas a todos.

El problema que tengo es que mi página no detecta el scroll he probado todos los códigos que vais subiendo para solucionar este problema y ninguno me ha funcionado... Es una página muy simple y básica, tiene un hoja html, css y js. tengo efecto parallax muy básico y sencillo con css ¿eso puede afectar a que jquery no detecte el scroll? Os dejo abajo un código que me sirvió para saber si jquery funciona o no..Al abrir la pagina me sale alerta jquery funcionando, le doy a click y el background de #menudiv cambia de color.

Numero 1 el 2 y 3 y unos cuantos mas que he probado no funcionan.

Y al hacer scroll sale en el console que estoy haciendo scroll pero cuando meto alguna función como: al llegar a 20% de la pagina, lo tipico como dejar la barra nav fix y que le cambie de color no me funciona he probado varios códigos y soluciones y nada.

También he probado en chrome firefox y opera en ninguno ha funcionado; tan solo sale la alerta nada mas.

1- Funciona

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("jQuery esta funcionando !!");
   $('#menudiv').css('background-color', 'blue');
 });


$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');

    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2- No funciona

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // When the event DOMContentLoaded occurs, it is safe to access the DOM

  // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
  window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);

  // Get the navbar
  var navbar = document.getElementById("nav");

  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. 
  // Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position

  function myFunctionForSticky() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      console.log("window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    } else {
      console.log("Not window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }

  /*Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav
  when the user clicks on the icon*/

  function myFunctionForResponsive() {
    navbar.classList.toggle('responsive');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3- No funciona

```js
window.onscroll = changePos;

function changePos() {
    var header = document.getElementById("nav");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
        header.style.position = "fixed";
        header.style.top = "0";
    } else {
        header.style.position = "";
        header.style.top = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y asi con varios y ninguno me ha funcionado.

Comment: hola @Trah bienvenido a stakoverflo, te recomiendo que leas como preguntar para que puedas formular una pregunta entendible

Comment: Utiliza la versión minificada de jquery es por eso

Comment: Gracias @Enzo No soy español y el idioma español lo hablo poco.